# Thrift service as a bundle in OSGI

Tags: maven, osgi, thrift

I was creating a simple Calculator service in thrift as a bundle in OSGI. The src/lib contains all the dependent jars, and they have been included in the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
         <groupId>commons-lang-2.4</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-lang-2.4</artifactId>
         <scope>system</scope>
         <version>2.4</version>
         <systemPath>${basedir}\src\lib\commons-lang-2.4.jar</systemPath>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>httpcore-4.1.3</groupId>
         <artifactId>httpcore-4.1.3</artifactId>
         <scope>system</scope>
         <version>4.1.3</version>
         <systemPath>${basedir}\src\lib\httpcore-4.1.3.jar</systemPath>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>httpclient-4.0-alpha4</groupId>
         <artifactId>httpclient-4.0-alpha4</artifactId>
         <scope>system</scope>
         <version>4.0</version>
         <systemPath>${basedir}\src\lib\httpclient-4.0-alpha4.jar</systemPath>
      </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.thrift-0.9.0</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.thrift-0.9.0</artifactId>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <version>0.9.0</version>
    <systemPath>${basedir}\src\lib\org.apache.thrift-0.9.0.jar</systemPath>
  </dependency>
   </dependencies>
```

Also the imported package has references to :

```
<Import-Package>
              org.apache.commons.logging,
              org.apache.felix.dm,
              org.apache.thrift,
              org.apache.thrift.async,
              org.apache.thrift.meta_data,
              org.apache.thrift.protocol,
              org.apache.thrift.scheme,
              org.apache.thrift.server,
              org.apache.thrift.transport
       ......
```

It compiles fine but the bundle refuses to come up :

!Message framework Event Error
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The Bundle "org.thrift.northbound_0.4.0:SNAPSHOT[95]" could not be resolved. Reason:Missing Constraint Import-Package: org.apache.thift ; version="[0.9.0, 1.0.0)"

Any pointers as to what am I missing ?

Comment: Reason:Missing Constraint Import-Package: org.apache.thift 

Missing an 'r', or is that a transcription error? Why not not let bnd figure out your imports?

Comment: Hi Peter, its actually a transcript error. How do i let bnd figure out the impotrs--any pointers ?

Comment: Just leave out the <Import-Package/> element. The default is that bnd calculates the import.

Comment: Since we had some other imports can't leave out that , but using a wildcard character * and putting in the dependency works as a magic